# Python - How to use string in index

Tags: python, python-3.x

Was wondering how you would use a string that is equal to an interger as the integer in an index.

```
word = input("Enter word:")
print(word)
letterNum = int(len(word)) #determines amount of letters in word
print(letterNum)
lastLetter = word[letterNum] #supposed to figure out the last letter in a word
print(lastLetter)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by 'string that is equal to an integer as the integer in an index'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you the last letter in a word without all the code. I'm unsure what you're asking by index though.

```
word = input("Enter word: ")
print(word[-1])
```

Example:

```
Enter word: Test
#"t"
```

If you're asking if `"Test 1"` was input and you want to get the last character as a number then it's as simple as wrapping it in `int` but do some checking first.

```
word = input("Enter word: ")
last_char = word[-1]

if isnumeric(word[-1]):
    print(int(last_char))
else:
    print(last_char)
```

Examples:

```
Enter word: Test 1
#1

Enter word: Test
#"t"
```

Comment: Is there a way to use a variable as the integer though?

Comment: @Turtle yes just where I'm printing it just put `variable = int(last_char)`

Comment: but in the array index thing, like if i made num=2 is there a way i could do word1[num], word2[num], word3[(num-1)], etc

Comment: Absolutely! That's definitely legal use. please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/225020) great answer to understand better what's going on in mine and @KayEss's answer. but as long as the num is within `0 -- len(word)-1` then `word[num]` will return that character in the string

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way with python is to index using `-1`. Negative indexes count from the end of the string so `word[-1]` will always give you the last letter

Comment: is there a way to use a string there though?

Answer (score 1):

Here I am giving you few of the examples including above.

```
word = input("Enter word:").strip() # strip() is used to remove any trailing or leading white spaces
print(word)
letterNum = int(len(word)) # Determines amount of letters in word
print(letterNum)

# 1st way (Using the internet that we created above) 
lastLetter = word[letterNum - 1] # Supposed to figure out the last letter in a word
print(lastLetter)

# 2nd way (As the above answers suggest, -ve index, -1 for last, -2 for 2nd last, this is best, but this basically for Python, other language like C/C++ etc. use 1st way) 
print(word[-1]) 

# 3rd way (Not good, but it is good for those who are learning Python,Reversing the string and printing 1st character) 
print(word[::-1][0])
```